# Opencart 3.0. Doesn't change colomn_left in admin panel

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

I try to change my admin panel and add new column to left column
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ki4r.png)

I change file admin/controller/common/left_column.php

```
if ($this->user->hasPermission('access', 'customer/cards')) {
    $customer[] = array(
         'name'    => $this->language->get('text_customer_card'),
         'href'     => $this->url->link('customer/cards', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token'], true),
         'children' => array()
    );
}
```

I clean browser and opencart cache. But nothing changes!
What to do? Help me, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just forgot to clear the mod cache. Thanks.